# Modify colour text if value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am passing to my .ejs file an array *todolist* of *todo* objects. The keys of such object are: Action / Date / Priority

I print out those keys values and I want to have the priority text print in red if priority is >3  / print in orange if priority is ==3 / print in green if priority is <=2. If it's not clear it'll become clearer looking at the code.

Here is the concerned piece of my code:

```
    <ul id= "list1">
    <% todolist.forEach(function(todo, index) { %>
        <li><a href="/todo/supprimer/<%= index %>">✘</a> 
            <%= todo.action %> <%=todo.date%> (priorité: <div id="prio<%index%>"><%=todo.priority%>/5)</div>
        </li>
    <% }); %>
    </ul>

    <script>
        $('#list1 div').each(function() {
            if ($(this).text() <= 2) $(this).css('color', 'green');
            if ($(this).text() == 3 ) $(this).css('color', 'orange');
            else (this).css('color', 'green');
            console.log("i'm in");
            });
    </script>
```

Is it possible that my function is in conflict with an extern css stylesheet? 
Also, I can't get the "i'm in" in my console, I don't understand why... 
If someone could help me, thanks

Comment: Where is this script on your page in relation to the markup?  Also can you provide the generated markup rather than the templating?

Comment: text() will return string, not number, you have to convert it to number...

Comment: this style becomes inline style, so only !important ones can override thm

Comment: @AbidNawaz that's not correct for jQuery object. $(selector).each is fine

Comment: @TemaniAfif I believe he is saying his inline styling is not being taken into effect, as if the css rules have an important else where.  But he says the console is not happening, suggesting the loop is not working.  Thus my asking the location of the script as it's not in a document ready.

Comment: @charlietfl yes there is, just the interpreter didn't format it.

Comment: @Taplar he said `Is it possible that my function is in conflict with an extern css stylesheet?` so replied to this :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif "Also, I can't get the "i'm in" in my console, I don't understand why.."  If his loop is not working, then the inline styles are not being applied in the first place.

Comment: @sinisake I've taken my code from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971569/html-and-css-changing-text-color-of-cell-depending-on-value and it worked well there without converting text to number. But I'll try it

Comment: @Taplar I corrected it

Comment: Ok, but that markup doesn't look like what your templating would render.  Can you please provide an example of the markup your templating is rendering?  And you didn't respond to where on the page the script is in relation to the markup; before or after.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code: `else (this).css` should be `else $(this).css`

Comment: @Taplar, I'm beginner in web devlopment and I've a bad knowledge of web nomenclature. If the markup is what belong into the <script> tag, then I call it after I printed the object values. A rendered object should look like this: Buy bread - 1 January (priorite: 5/5) with parenthesis and its content in the desired color

Comment: If the script is after the markup, then fix the typo @JonathanNicol pointed out and see if anything changes.  Also check your console for any other errors.

Comment: @RaphaëlPerun I wouldn't use javascript for this simple task.

Comment: @julekgwa I know, I just want to train my web skills and on a website they proposed to make a todolist in wich you can add, remove, modify, sort the todos. Whatever I learn here, I'll use in other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code: `else (this).css` should be `else $(this).css`. Also your if/else conditional is wonky. You have if/if/else, but I think you probably want if/elseif/else. I have corrected these things:

```
$('#list1 div').each(function() {
  var priority = $(this).text().substr(0,1);
  if (priority <= 2) $(this).css('color', 'green');
  else if (priority == 3 ) $(this).css('color', 'orange');
  else $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Edit: I have updated my answer to meet the requirement that comparison is done against the first character of each `<div>`'s content rather than the entire string.

Comment: Yes it works now ! Just the console doesn't output the text. And I've made a mistake, When higher than 3, text should be red. Thank you !

Comment: Sorry, I left a console.log in my answer by mistake! I have removed it just now, and updated my answer to reflect your requirement that values > 3 should be red.

Comment: I notice that you accepted my answer, but have subsequently unaccepted it. Is my solution not working as expected?

Comment: Yes, from the text I had to extract the <%=todo.priority%> value, because it's regarding this value we decide whether the text should be displayed in red, orange or green. And the solution given was always setting the text in the color stated by the else statment. What I did is (priorité:<div id="prio<%index%>"><%=todo.priority%>/5</div>) in the html and parseInt($(this).text()) in the Query script

Comment: Right. So what you're saying is that the `<div>` contains the number you actually care about followed by "/5". So the idea of using `.text()` to extract a number won't work, since the `<div>` actually contains a string. There are various options here: set the priority as a data-* attribute and compare against that; wrap the priority in a `<span>` and extract `text()` from that; split the string on "/" and compare against the first part. Let me know if you have a preferred approach and I will gladly update my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer to meet the requirement that comparison is done against the first character of each <div>'s content rather than the entire string.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I didn't know the existence of the data-* attribute. To use it, you suggest me to do something like in this [link](https://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1397-html5-attribut-data-dataset.html), and store $(this).getAttribute("priority") into a variable and compare it to the different values of my tests ?

Answer (score 0):

Use css class instead of Javascript

```
.red {
    color: red;
 }

 .green {
    color: green;
 }

 .orange {
    color: orange;
 }
```

Then in your loop, check the value of priority

```
<ul id= "list1">
<% todolist.forEach(function(todo, index) { %>
    <li><a href="/todo/supprimer/<%= index %>">✘</a> 
        <%= todo.action %> <%=todo.date%> (priorité: 
        <% if (todo.priority <= 2) { %>
            <div id="prio<%index%>" class="green"><%=todo.priority%>/5)</div>
        <% } else if (todo.priority == 3) { %>
            <div id="prio<%index%>" class="orange"><%=todo.priority%>/5)</div>
        <% } else if (todo.priority > 3) { %>
            <div id="prio<%index%>" class="red"><%=todo.priority%>/5)</div>
        <% } %>
    </li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you ! I didn't know we could do this all with the <%%> tags. But I supposed programmers usually avoid to write a code this way right?